# How to Make Textbox Visible And Invisible from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here i have textbox.Similarly, i have table tblpstatus which have two field id and Pstatus.
Now what i am trying do is, if the Field Pstatus have text V then textbox must be visible else not.
 Now the problem is that even if the field Pstatus have text V textbox are not visible.
Below is what i have:
Table tructure
id | Pstatus

1    |  V

Html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" placeholder="test" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/><br>
```

Code behind

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        DataTable dt = c.getpstatus();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0]["Pstatus"].ToString() == "V")
            {
                Button1.Visible = true;
                TextBox1.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                Button1.Visible = false;
                TextBox1.Visible = false;

            }


        }
    }
```

Method used

```
  public DataTable getpstatus()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
    string sql = "select * from tblpstatus";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps expand  a little more on your issue.  How many records are in tblpstatus?  If more than 1 the line "select * from tblpstatus" will give you all of them and potentially in an order you don't expect so the first record could have Pstatus != V.  I would suggest placing an order by or where clause at least to test and make sure you are getting a record that has Pstats == V such as select * from tblpstatus where pstatus = 'V'

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["Pstatus"].ToString().equals("V"))
```

Comment: @Matt by using "==" you are comparing references not the value,